# Why is my if statement not evaluating right?

Tags: python

The purpose of my code is to check how many times the given letter is in the given sentence. I made a function where it will take the user's sentence and letter as parameters and give the amount of times the letter is in the sentence. I haven't fully completed all the different scenarios so thats why I have a print statement in my if statement.

```
userstr = input("What is your sentence? ")
userletter = str(input("What is your letter? "))


def lettercount(sentence, letter):
    count = 0
    sentencecounter = 0
    for letter in sentence:
        if letter == sentence[sentencecounter]:
            print(sentence[sentencecounter])
            count += 1
        else:
            pass
        sentencecounter += 1
    print(count)


lettercount(userstr, userletter)
```

So my problem is that in my if statement it will continue as if the letter equals the sliced sentence letter even when it's not. Here's what it looks like

```
s
e
n
t
e
n
c
e
8
```

Comment: did u try the collection library?

Comment: your algorithm doesn't seem correct. What's the logic behind `sentencecounter` and it incrementing every time in the loop. On top of that, you're overwriting the `letter` parameter in your `lettercount` method with `for letter in sentence`. i.e the `letter` variable inside the loop is actually each element in `sentence`

Comment: debugging is a great tool, try printing `letter` everytime in the loop to see what's exactly happening. Because your algorithm doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @Chase I made it incrementing because I need to slice through every letter in the user's sentence

Comment: the reason `letter == sentence[sequencecounter]` is because they are the exact same thing. As I said in my previous comment, `letter` is each element in `sentence` due to the fact that you've overwritten its value in `for letter in sentence`

Comment: @Chase ok I see what you're saying

Comment: @dex But python for loops already do exactly that for you. `for letter in sentence` means you're going through every letter in the user's sentence and storing it in a variable called `letter`. Please read- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 0):

Change `letter` variable in for loop as it is same as `letter` in function paramters

```
lettercount(userstr, userletter)
userstr = input("What is your sentence? ")
userletter = str(input("What is your letter? "))


def lettercount(sentence, letter):
    count = 0
    sentencecounter = 0
    for ch in sentence:
        if letter == sentence[sentencecounter]:
            print(sentence[sentencecounter])
            count += 1
        else:
            pass
        sentencecounter += 1
    print(count)
```

Comment: this is wrong. `ch` and `sentence[sentencecounter]` are the same things. They will always be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `count` method to simplify the stuff.

```
def lettercount(sentence, letter):
    count = sentence.count(letter)
    print(count) # replace print with return if you wanna return the value

lettercount(userstr, userletter)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is problems with your function. I just fix it.

```
def lettercount(sentence, letter):
    count = 0
    sentencecounter = 0
    for i in sentence:
        if i == letter:
            print(i)
            count += 1
        else:
            pass
        sentencecounter += 1
    print(count)

userstr = input("What is your sentence? ")
userletter = str(input("What is your letter? "))

lettercount(userstr, userletter)
```